# Replacing a <DIV> after a set time

Tags: jquery, html, replace

I'm trying to replace DIV-A with DIV-B on a landing page after 10 seconds.

I've been looking round and JQUERY seems to be the best bet, but I'm not sure how to do it. There seems to be plenty of solutions for cycling DIVs, or replacing one on a button click, but I just need the first to be replaced by the second.

If there's any other easy solutions I'm open for anything. The site is HTML and I'm already using the minified JQUERY for something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:**

```
<head> 

  <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js'></script> 

  <script type='text/javascript'> 

  $(window).load(function(){
  setTimeout(
   function(){

      $('#Div-A').replaceWith($('#Div-B'));
      $('#Div-B').show();

   },
   10000
);
  });

  </script> 

</head> 
<body> 
  <div id="Div-A">BOOOOOO</div> 
<div id="Div-B" style="display:none;">YAAAAAA</div> 


</body>
```

**Here is a working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/mpeXp/

Comment: @El thanks! =) I just discovered that function recently. Its been a ton of help

Comment: @ Ima Thanks, still not sure I'm doing this right... below is my code, and apologies for showing my ignorance! Is this using JQUERY or just javascript in the head?

Comment: <head>

<script src="js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
 
 $('#DIV-A').delay(10000).replaceWith('#Div-B');

</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="div-A">BOOOOOO</div>

<div id="div-B">YAAAAAA</div>

</body>

</html>

Comment: Do you want div-b to be visible before it replaces div-a?

Comment: @ Ima No a straight swap, I have to display a disclaimer before the user can click though. i.e div-a (disclaimer) for 10 sec then it gets swapped out for div-b (a block of text and a next page link).

Comment: @oh then its better to have a setTimeout

Comment: @ Ima Thanks Ima, you're a legend! I was nearly there. Many many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to have a timeout to trigger the replacement. Then you'll need to find the parent of DIV-A, remove DIV-A, then add DIV-B to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
setTimeout(
   function(){
       //what to do after 10 seconds
       $('#divA').hide();
       $('#divB').show();
       //or some other code
   },
   10000
); //done :-)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can mix jquery and setTimeout to achieve this:

```
var timeout_period = 1000;//in miliseconds so 1000 = 1 second
setTimeout ("$('#div-A').html( $('#div-B').html() );", timeout_period );
```

Comment: note that the above doesn't actually replace div-A with div-B but **their contents**!

Comment: do not do that to combine divs, then if you ever want to go back to the orig divA you cannot in your instance

Comment: @Liv also stop adding comments to all you answers, add it to your **actual answer**...

Comment: appreciate the comment about putting the whole answer in the original answer -- point taken. However, I don't understand your comment about "if you want to go back to divA you can't" -- pray do explain!

Comment: in your example the user cannot go back to original contents of `div-A` because they were replaced by the contents of `div-B`

Comment: I don't belive that was a requirement whatsoever in the question, was there? In fact the question states clearly that divA needs to be replaced with divB -- no mention of being able to reference the previous contents of divA - so don't understand why you voted my answer down?

Comment: ok. point taken. i cant undownvote unless the answer is edited with an explanation.

Comment: and ironically, having moaned about me structuring my answers in 2 parts (answer + comment) you went and did the same: came up with an argument against my comment (totally unjustified), and then came back the very next minute with another comment telling me i shouldn't do ... well exactly what you did! What would you call this behaviour?

Comment: lol when i posted my 1st comment your comment was not there :-p

Comment: @Neal I feel like this is an appropriate time to tell you that your flag picture looks like a crushed soda can :p

Comment: @Neal lol your argument or the flag? but the answer is yes to both. Timing is crucial

Comment: @Neal yes I did but I cannot unsee the soda can when I see your thumbnail. Just thought you should know ;)

Comment: @Ima student, i rly dont see a soda can hehe

Comment: Hi Everyone, Many thanks for the answers, sorry for being a bit dim, I'm a designer, not a natural java developer! (mind you you could probably tell from my original post)

Comment: @Ima @Neal @Liv I'm not worried about going back to the original div, it's a legal disclaimer. If I use the above script, so i put that in the scrip tags in the <head>? and how should I treat the <div>s in the body? as display: none? or does the javascript do the hiding?

Comment: @Ben use my script! The greatest part about it is that you don't need to use much css. You can just position your Div-A and Div-B can be wherever you'd like.

Comment: @Ima Student the above code doesn't do any hiding/showing of the divs -- but only handling the content transfer. you can put this in your `<head>` section or at the end of of your page before `<body>` inside a `<script>` tag.